# Attributes dont appear in eclipse in programming time

Tags: java, eclipse

When, for instance declaring a new integer variable in java let's say `int number=7;` if I write in Eclipse `a.`, it does not appear on the right all the possible attributes that could be used, as it should do. I have tryed installing a new version of Eclise but it does not make any difference. Does anyone know how to fix this?

PS: I tried to look in google for an image of the event i'm talking about and is similar to the one provided bellow but in my case for java programming.
[image: http://blogs.telerik.com/images/default-source/kendoui-blog-posts/windows-live-writer-kendo-ui-winter-release_e3dc-eclipse_intellisense_on_tag_thumb-png]

Comment: can you show your code snippet which declares the `int number` and which tries to access it ?

Comment: it would be exactly as in the example, but it does not matter the variable type being declared, the problem is that the extra help provided by eclipse as show in the image does not appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you well, here is the solution for autocompletion:
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced
You click restore default and that should be it.